# Git how to delete some ignored files when changing branch

Tags: eclipse, git, branch

I have a project with two versions of my code, one "maintenance" and one "new" for a newer version.

I wanted to ignore all *.min.js files in my code in these branchs. Some .js files are in "new" but not in "maintenance". Eclipse generates .min.js everytime a .js file is edited.

The problem is, when i'm on branch "new" and switch to branch "maintenance", the minified js generated in new and that don't have their .js files on maintenance are still there.

Is there a way to tell git to delete these files when switching to maintenance ?

I would like to defined a merge strategy in gitattributes instead of ignoring .min.js files, but Eclipse doesn't handle gitattriutes.

Comment: Eclipse reads the `.gitattributes` files. Which specific `.gitattributes` setting do you think Eclipse is ignoring?

Comment: I tried to implement it for crlf, was wondering why it didn't work and found out that Egit doesn't manage gitattributes. on egit's github, you can see "gitattributes support" in missing features https://github.com/eclipse/egit I am currently trying to implement merge.theirs.driver

Comment: The page of the mirrored Git repository you are referring to is not up-to-date [as you can see in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TM9DBinKQdI&t=213s) (it also does not say that `.gitattributes` is completely ignored). Make sure to use the latest version of Eclipse and EGit. Please explain your idea of the merge strategy. I don't know what you mean by that and how it could solve your problem.

Comment: The idea was to determine a merge "ours" or "theirs" (doesn't matter) to avoid getting useless conflicts on *.min.js that will be re-generated. Git takes one or another file, doesn't create conflicts and Eclipse regenerates a new .min.js
I tries gitattributes "merge=ours" and it works well in command line but not with Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of an untracked file is that Git does not know anything about it.  Git therefore cannot know to *remove* it either.

Git *does* provide a general mechanism to let you run your own operations after each `git checkout`, namely what it calls a *post-checkout hook*.  (Whether your Eclipse IDE obeys this same protocol, I have no idea.)  The post-checkout hook is simply any executable file<sup>1</sup> named `.git/hooks/post-checkout`.  Git will run it, with some arguments as described in [the githooks documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks/#_post_checkout), after each `git checkout`.

Since `git checkout` *can* be used for operations that are not *change the branch name to which `HEAD` is attached*, you will need to test for whatever conditions you deem appropriate.  For instance, you could check the third parameter, the one called *`flag`* in the documentation.  If it is set, the command was an operation that modified the commit or branch name to which `HEAD` is bound.  If `HEAD` is now bound to a commit or branch in which some `*.min.js` files should be removed if they exist, you can now remove them if they exist.  If `HEAD` is now bound to a commit or branch in which some `*.min.js` files should be created if they do not exist, you can now create them if they do not exist.

Such a script might look like this, although you will need to fill in the missing parts:

```
#! /bin/sh
# Post-checkout hook to deal with `*.min.js` files.

# If flag is not 1, do nothing (and succeed).
if [ "$3" != 1 ]; then exit 0; fi

# Otherwise, determine whether there are *.min.js files that need to
# be created and/or removed.  The code below is meant to be illustrative,
# not efficient.

for file in $(compute files that should be removed); do rm -f "$file"; done
for file in $(compute files that should be created); do create_minified "$file"; done

exit 0 # always report success, regardless of actual success
```

That last line is important: the Git documentation claims that the post-checkout hook cannot affect the outcome of `git checkout`, but in fact, the exit status of the post-checkout hook sets the exit status of `git checkout` itself.  If your post-checkout hook reports a failure-status, `git checkout` will report a failure-status, which may mislead larger automated systems.  This could be good or bad, depending on your point of view, so while the last line is *important*, it's not necessarily *correct* for your particular application.

---

<sup>1</sup>An *executable file*, here, must be *actually executable*.  That is, it not only needs to have the `x` bit set (on a Unix-like system, use `chmod +x` or `chmod 755` or similar to set the executable bits), it must be *directly executable via an `execve` system call*.  For scripts on Unix-like systems, this means the script must begin with a line like `#! /bin/sh` or `#! /usr/bin/env bash`, where the path name after `#!` is the path name of the interpreter.  Python scripts may be made executable via `#! /usr/bin/env python` or `#! /usr/bin/env python3.6` or the like, depending on which Python interpreter you need to invoke.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ! I didn't know about git hooks and I learnt a lot ! I tried and it works well in command line, sadly when I try with Eclipse the hook is not executed. I will still mark it as the solution since I don't think I will find a better one

Answer (score 0):

After switching to `new` branch, you can run the following command to make the working tree match the HEAD state.

```
git reset --hard && git clean -dfx
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I would like git to delete automatically these files, and I can't do a git clean because some other ignored files are needed in both branchs

Comment: With Eclipse you can use Git without having Git installed on the command line (thanks to Eclipse JGit which is a Git implementation in Java).